# WCF Design: Avoiding Interface Duplication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm finding myself drawn to using two identical interfaces in this scenario which doesn't seem right.  However the alternative appears to be to use a WCF decorated interface from within my service which also feels wrong.

Example follows

Here is the interface for my WCF Service

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://MyNameSpace")]
public interface IGetDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<MyDataObject> GetData();
}
```

Now, lets say the service only gets data from the database.  I need an implementation to facilitate this retrieval. Should this class also implement IGetDataService as the methods are identical?  Or should I have another interface, called for example, IDataRepository:

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    List<MyDataObject> GetData();
}
```

Note that this interface is identical to IGetDataService in terms of signature.  The only difference is the lack of WCF related attributes.

```
class DatabaseDataRepository: IDataRepository
{
    public List<MyDataObject> GetData()
    {
        //  code to query database here
        //  return populated List<MyDataObject>
    }
}
```

And as for the implementation of the WCF service itself (for completeness):

```
class DataService: IGetDataService
{
    public List<MyDataObject> GetData()
    {
        var repository = MyIocContainer.GetInstance<IDataRepository>();
        return repository.GetData();
    }
}
```

So, to summarise: do I need IDataRepository or is IGetDataService reusable internally?

I'm fairly confident both would work - interested in design best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference.

I would use two different interfaces. It's a little more overhead but it allows the two contracts to flex in different directions.

For example, if your WCF service needs to expose a new service, you don't have to change your repository interface as well.

Comment: Thanks @Derek Van Cuyk.  Agree with your statement.  Also, thinking about it, having two interfaces would be the code much clearer for anyone who has to pick it up.  Using an implementation of IGetDataService within the service could be a bit confusing